# Resizable column header in QTableView not working in pyqt5

Tags: pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 even then I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'QHeaderView' object has no attribute 'setSectionResizeMode'
```

I thought `setSectionResizeMode` exists in PyQt5 instead of PyQt4's `setResizeMode`

I even tried this following the similar issue on SO :

```
self.table_view.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
```

but still getting same Attribute error.

Comment: provide  a [mre]